# Issue with free(); with a 2 dimensions array of which one is known in C

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

i want to free();after using malloc , a 2 dimensions array that one of the dimensions is known . Lets take for example the array psi[i][3]; I am asked for the array t be type of unsigned int of which i dont know  the size of i , so i have done it like this :

```
unsigned int (*psi)[3] = malloc(i * sizeof *psi);

if((psi)[3] == NULL ) {
    printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
    exit(0);
});



 free(psi);
```

The problem with the above is that although i have declared the psi array as an unsigned int like the above, i am getting this error only in free :

```
error 257 [Error] 'psi' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I would appreciate your help and thank you all for your time!

Comment: `if((psi)[3] == NULL )` should be `if (psi == NULL )`

Comment: "i have declared the psi array as an unsigned int  ..." --> recall `psi` is a pointer,  not an array.

Comment: are you trying to highlight the code lines with `**` or something? That can get quite confusing mixed in with C code ... Please just post the code you're feeding to your compiler.

Comment: please post a [mre]. Your error is probably a variable scoping issue, but that's not shown in what you've posted.

Comment: OT: `exit(0)` is conventionally used to indicate "all went well"... Since you have to include `stdlib.h` for the function `exit()`, why not use `EXIT_FAILURE` when things go wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Typedefs help tremendously. Here is your fixed-size inner dimension:

```
typedef int three_ints[3];
```

Now you can more easily allocate a dynamic array of them:

```
three_ints * psi = malloc( nrows * sizeof(three_ints) );
if (!psi) {
  complain();
}
```

And free them:

```
free( psi );
```

As with any 2D array, you can iterate over it with the usual syntax:

```
for (int row = 0;  row < nrows;  row++)
{
  for (int col = 0;  col < 3;  col++)
    printf( "\t%d", psi[row][col] );
  printf( "\n" );
}
```

Comment: On the contrary, hiding arrays behind typedef is often considered unreadable and dangerous, similar to hiding pointers behind typedef. Many would consider this code obfuscation. Even if you don't agree with that, you still end up preaching subjective coding styles.

Comment: No, you are preaching a hardcore C-ideologue position that does not exist across industry. There is nothing wrong with giving a type a name, _even if that type is an array_.

Comment: There's plenty wrong, since like hiding pointers behind typedef, it hides away important information for the programmer. The Windows API is a commonly used example of a completely broken type system to serve as a warning for others. The problem with hiding things like this is that they are still arrays, so they don't play by the same rules like the common types that they seem to be at a glance. Consider `type try_this (void)`.

Comment: Either way, the question is just about a simple syntax error...

Comment: Generally, one should not hide a "array-ness" behind the `typedef`. It will likely bite when this type is ever used as a *function parameter*. C23 will support `typeof` that will allow using a bit more readable syntax for declaring array/function pointers of complex types: `typeof(unsigned int[3])* psi = calloc(nrows, sizeof *psi);`

Comment: You can ignore the so called “advice” not to `typedef` arrays. I have not seen good examples or data showing this has any significant effect on bugs or engineering cost. E.g., the offered “The Windows API is a commonly used example of a completely broken type system to serve as a warning for others” is at most circular reasoning, giving the Windows API has an example that is bad because it serves as a warning or something; no actual consequences are related. The offered sample code, `type try_this (void)`, results immediately in a compiler error message and is easily dealt with…

Comment: … It appears to be just a meme that spreads from person to person because other people say it, and then more people repeat it, without good reason.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I was once hit by `memset(x, sizeof x)` in `void foo(X x)` function where X was a typedef-ed array. A part of an array was not zeros, ... occasionally. It took me a longer than necessary debugging session to find it. Now I try to avoid `typedef`-ing arrays. They are too different from the other classes of types.

Comment: @tstanisl: Okay, there is a problem there, but why is the lesson “Do not `typedef` an array”? If that were the rule, then somebody might encapsulate the array in a structure, and then you would be passing a large amount of data by value. That is not the solution we want. Further, there is a second problem, you are setting the raw bytes of a type whose representation you do not know. There is a different lesson to learn, one that addresses all three of these problems: Document the types you export to clients…

Comment: … The party defining the type needs to tell the type’s clients how to use it, including how to initialize it and how to pass it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, you are right, documentation is important. However, "arrayness" is not something that can be hidden by `typedef` without significant "abstraction leaks". That is why some people prefer to always make array declaration explicit and as close to the actual usage as possible. And distinguish non-arrays for function parameters in `int(int[3])` in favor of `int(int*)`/`int(int[])`/`int(int[static 3])`.